# Docker container runs on mac but not windows

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile, go-gin

I have a docker container for a gin web server. When I try ir on my macbook it runs but on windows docker desktop the container exits with error: exec ./hello: no such file or directory

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run()
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:latest AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ .

RUN go build -o /app/hello

FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/hello .

CMD ["/app/hello"]
```

Comment: On Windows, the Path is different. From what I recall, there's an option to check inside your Windows Docker local application.

Comment: Are you using the exact same image between the two systems (for example, `docker push`ed to a registry) or are you rebuilding it on the other system?  It looks like you might be using a Debian-based builder image but an Alpine-based runtime, and Go containers seem particularly prone to trouble if these don't match; for example [Installed Go binary not found in path on Alpine Linux Docker](/q/34729748).

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the assist. Building it on the alpine container instead of the Debian-based container works

Answer (score 1):

changing the builder container to an alpine container solved this

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
```